# C# Culture Name for Angola?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I want to get Angolan culture in order to use something like this:

```
var cultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-PT");
var price = String.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C}", price);
```

to format price in kwanzas when the user is from Angola, but I don't know and I can't find what to use instead of `"pt-PT"` for Angola, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: It could be C# does not support the Angolan culture directly (ao-AO or pt-AO, not sure). What version of .NET are you using? If you happen to use 4.0 or above, you can create your own culture, based on an existing one

Comment: If I remember correctly, CultureInfo supports whatever _your version of Windows_ supports. You may have to install some kind of language pack for Angola or something, if that exists.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten, you are absolutely correct. The problem for the OP would be if he personally has that installed, but if he is making a web application, then what matters is if the culture is present on the server. If so, he could not test at home how it will behave on the server

Comment: Just a remark on the side: you should never format prices with the user's culture, because $ != € != kwanza. If a price is 10 USD, then show 10 USD, not 10 kwanza. And if you do need to show kwanza, you may need to convert.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten in this particular case it realy works like that, just have to change currency without converting values. Where can i get such a language pack?

Comment: @FabioG No idea. In the Windows settings somewhere?

Comment: Ok it seems this is not an option... gonna have to go with a custom culture as @IvayloSlavov suggested

Comment: On my system, Windows 8.1 with newest .NET Framework version, there ***is*** a `"pt-AO"` culture info, as expected, but as others said that depends on your OS version and whether you installed updated regional info.

Comment: The string `ao` is not (as of now) assigned to any two-letter ISO language code, so it wouldn't be `"ao-AO"`. Note that there is [no language called "Angolan"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Angola). But you were right about `"pt-AO"`; as I just wrote above, it works on my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As from some research I did, it seems Windows installations do not originally support the Angolan culture settings. This is important to notice, because .NET *does not itself come up with culture settings* - it takes the settings from the installed cultures on the OS.

So here are a few approaches you can go for:

- Install the appropriate culture as a language pack for the OS, if such is available. This will make your application work **only** on that computer. Other computers or web server hosting environments (if you happen to make a website) must also install the same language pack. I'd consider this approach somewhat unacceptable, as it depends on external prerequisite and involves some non-trivial work on each party that would run your application. Thus, I'd take a look at the other approach
- Create a custom culture within your application. Since v4.0, the .NET framework allows you to build custom cultures based on the existing ones. This will give you the following benefits:

  - Have total control on how that culture represents information.
  - The culture is created by your application. It does not require additional effort by you, or your users and it will work anywhere.

In short, if you want to create a custom culture in .NET, you need to run **once** a similar to this piece of code:

```
CultureInfo baseCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-PT");
RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo(baseCulture.Name);

CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder builder =
    new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("pt-AO",CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);

// load in the data from the existing culture and region
builder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(baseCulture);
builder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(regionInfo);

// make custom changes to the culture
builder.CurrencyEnglishName = ...;
builder.CurrencyNativeName = ...;
builder.ISOCurrencySymbol = ...;

builder.Register();
```

I assume the Angolan culture will be very close to `pt-PT` culture, therefore I am using it as a base. You can change it however suits you best. You also need to replace the `...` values in my code with what are the correct ones for your culture. I do not know them so I'm leaving these for you.

Another thing to notice - it is important for the above code to be executed once per application. Otherwise, the `builder.Register()` method could throw an exception if a culture with that name is already registered. This also implies avoiding existing culture names for your custom culture.

---

You can take a look at these resources on how to make a custom culture:

- [Custom Cultures on MSDN pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Another article on custom cultures](http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/Using_Custom_Cultures%E2%80%94Supplemental_Substitute_Custom_Cultures)
- [A CodeProject article on overcomming Persian Calendar issues with the original culture](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256104/Using-Custom-Culture-Approach-to-Fix-Persian-Cutur)
- [An article on naming custom cultures appropriately](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=664144&seqNum=7)

Comment: did it yesterday, but it's still the correct answer